# d3.js: Scatterplot, stack filter/dropdown effects & handle same datapoints

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, dropdown

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/DW8QYHb3p1la68KBTPof?p=preview

```
    dropDownDate.on("change", function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        displayOthers = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
        display = this.checked ? "none" : "inline";

        if(selected == 'All'){
        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .attr("display", display);

        }

        else{
        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .filter(function(d) {return selected != d.date;})
            .attr("display", displayOthers);

        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.date;})
            .attr("display", display);

        }
    });

    dropDownInd.on("change", function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        displayOthers = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
        display = this.checked ? "none" : "inline";

        if(selected == 'All'){
        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .attr("display", display);
        }

        else{
        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .filter(function(d) {return selected != d.industry;})
            .attr("display", displayOthers);    
        svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
            .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.industry;})
            .attr("display", display);
        }
    });
```

There are 2 things I like to achieve:
1) *Make the filter/dropdown list effect stack*, as of now, say I use the 1st filter **date**, then 2nd filter **industry**, the effect of 2nd filter will overwrite the 1st filter

2) *How to handle same datapoints*. If you refer to the 1st 2 objects in the **orderInfo.json**, they have the same volume and date, hence you only see 1 circle for that value. What is the best way to differentiate the points from each other despite having same position?

For the x-axis it might look strange now because I only add data for 2 days.

Comment: About 2): will your dots always have the same color? If yes you can make a larger dot according to the number of dots in the same place (with radius= sqrt(n) to have a linear area).

Comment: @tarulen, it can be of different color as well, I am not entirely sure what would be the best way to handle same datapoints. I thought that even if they have different color, it would be hard for me to differentiate the 2 points due to narrow margin. If I align circles with same value along x-axis, it wouldn't be feasible when say I have 40 circles with identical values.

Comment: If you end up with many dots in the same place, you'd better put a single disk with the count inside, so maybe it'd be good to start already at 2. This is a typical use case of `d3.nest`.  With different colors, you can go for side-by-side or maybe pie-like.